# Find the inverse a matrix with trigonometic entries

Tags: matrices, inverse

What is the inverse of
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&\cos x &\sin x\\ 0 &\sin x &-\cos x \end{pmatrix}
\]
Please help me to solve the above problem.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. If you don't do this, people are less likely to answer your later questions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_x :=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos x & \sin x \\ \sin x & -\cos x \end{array} \right]$, and let $R_x :=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos x & -\sin x \\ \sin x & \cos x \end{array} \right]$ be the matrix of the rotation by angle $x$ in the plane (that is, for all ${\bf v}$ in $\mathbb R^2$, $\ R_x\cdot {\bf v}$ is the rotated version of $\bf v$), we have that
$$A_x = R_x\cdot \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array} \right]\ \text{ and }\  (R_x)^{-1} = R_{-x} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x \end{array} \right]\text{, so} $$
$$(A_x)^{-1} =  \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array} \right]\cdot R_{-x}$$
So, by easy matrix multiplication, one can verify that the additional $1$ in the additional dimension is not hurting much, ie. the requested inverse is:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0 &\cos x & \sin x \\ 0 & \sin x & -\cos x \end{array} \right] $$

Comment: Maybe it is too early in the morning, but should the signs on sin x both be positive (maybe since this is a rotation matrix, it does not matter)?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it does matter. As the next answer calculates, it is not the same..

Comment: ...and we thus see that the given matrix is in fact orthogonal.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the formula $\def\adj{\operatorname{adj}}A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\cdot \adj A$

Find $\det A$

$\det A=\begin{vmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\cos x &\sin x\\ 0 &\sin x &-\cos x \end{vmatrix}=-1$

Find $\adj A$

$A_{11}=(-1)^{1+1}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} \cos x & \sin x \\ \sin x & -\cos x \end{array} \right\rvert=-1$

$A_{12}=(-1)^{1+2}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \sin x \\ 0 & -\cos x \end{array} \right\rvert=0$

$A_{13}=(-1)^{1+3}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \cos x \\ 0 & \sin x \end{array} \right\rvert=0$

$A_{21}=(-1)^{2+1}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ \sin x & -\cos x \end{array} \right\rvert=0$

$A_{22}=(-1)^{2+2}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\cos x \end{array} \right\rvert=-\cos x$

$A_{23}=(-1)^{2+3}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sin x \end{array} \right\rvert=-\sin x$

$A_{31}=(-1)^{3+1}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ \cos x & \sin x \end{array} \right\rvert=0$

$A_{32}=(-1)^{3+2}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sin x \end{array} \right\rvert=-\sin x$

$A_{33}=(-1)^{3+3}\left\lvert \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos x \end{array} \right\rvert=\cos x$

$A^{-1}=\left\lvert \begin{array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0 &\cos x & \sin x \\ 0 & \sin x & -\cos x \end{array} \right\rvert$